# Meteor app cannot be run on iOS after Xcode upgrade

Tags: ios, xcode, meteor

I was developing Meteor project and was able to test it on both Android and iOS. But after my Xcode upgraded to version 7.3 I'm not able to test project on iOS anymore. Now I'm getting error:

> Check that you have Xcode 6.x installed

Is there any way to run my project while having Xcode 7 or do I need to downgrade it? My Meteor version is 1.3

Comment: Could you please try to start Xcode once and finish the installation?

Comment: It works. Thank you. But now I can run app only on iPhone 6s Plus simulator (it starts automatically if I don't have any other simulator running). If I start another simulator before executing _meteor run ios_ then Meteor console prints _Started app on iOS Simulator_ but actually nothing happens in the simulator. How I can run my app on some specific simulator?

Comment: Glad it worked! Please ask a new question, since this seems like a different issue.